# Overridden core class does not work when in artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, inversion-of-control

In a fresh Laravel build, I cannot get overridden IoC bindings to work everywhere in the application.

Suppose a service provider that overrides a core class, e.g. cache:

```
class NewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('cache', function($app) {
            return new \stdClass; // demo purpose
        });
    }

    public function provides()
       {
        return ['cache'];
    }
}
```

The provider is then added at the bottom of `app.providers` config.

Now modify `routes.php` to the following and go check the result:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    dd(app('cache'));
});

// Results in an empty stdClass being shown. It works!
```

However, fire up `artisan tinker` and do the same:

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> app('cache')
=> Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager
```

Suddenly the override isn't working anymore...

The same behavior is encountered when processing event listeners...

Is this normal behavior and am I overlooking something? Or is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to track down the issue myself.

It seems Artisan loads all deferred providers at once using a key-sorted providers array:

```
...
"cache" => NewServiceProvider,
"cache.store" => CacheServiceProvider,
...
```

As you can see, the `cache.store` binding calls the built-in `CacheServiceProvider` afterwards and hence renders
our `cache` binding useless since it contains the binding that we need to override).

So I'm obliged to have `NewServiceProvider` extend `CacheServiceProvider`, and call `parent::register()` to have the providers array converted to:

```
...
"cache" => NewServiceProvider,
"cache.store" => NewServiceProvider,
...
```

This seems like the only way to have the overridden cache binding being resolved correctly in Artisan.